# Loop through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this -

```
    [{"name":"admission[year]","value":"2011-12"},{"name":"admission[class]","value":"Nursery"}]
```

How can i access the name value pairs like admission[year] - 2011-12, and admission[class] - nursery in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = [{"name":"admission[year]","value":"2011-12"},{"name":"admission[class]","value":"Nursery"}]
var i, len = x.length;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    console.log(x[i].name + ': ' + x[i].value);
```

Outputs:

```
admission[year]: 2011-12
admission[class]: Nursery
```

IE. `x[0].name === "admission[year]"` and `x[1].value === "Nursery"`

Comment: Instead of i and len you can use "for (i in x)" - no boundary condition exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*

using jquery you can do something like this 

*/

$.each( ['a','b','c'], function(key, value){
   alert( "Index #" + key + ": " + value );
 });
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{ "name": "admission[year]", "value": "2011-12" }, { "name": "admission[class]", "value": "Nursery"}];
for (element in arr) {
    var combinedValue = arr[element].name + ' ' + arr[element].value;
    alert(combinedValue);
}
```